# How should I debug EnterpriseLibrary incompatibility issues between multiple installed excel add-Ins?

Tags: c#, com, excel-addins, enterprise-library-5

I am having compatibilities issue with another Excel COM Add-In. My COM Add-In uses EnterpriseLibrary.Caching block for caching in the application.

While creating msi using VS2010 I am adding the strong name assemblies to GAC folder. I am adding following assemblies.

[image: List of assemblies and its dependencies]

It seems to be clashing with another COM add-In. If loaded independently in excel they both work fine. But if loaded together my application throws following error.

"Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Validation' or one of its dependencies. Invalid pointer (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000403 (E_POINTER))"

I am not using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Validation anywhere in the application. My config section looks

```
<configSections>
    <section name="cachingConfiguration" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Caching.Configuration.CacheManagerSettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Caching, Version=5.0.505.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
```

It works if I use older version of EnterpriseLibrary  v4.1.0.0.

Where should I look to resolve this issue?

ps: Can't use fusion at the moment. :)

Comment: lol, can't use fusion logging due to company restrictions? You need fusion logging.  Go up the chain until they grant you this risky, destructive, possibly recession and/or zombie apocalypse inducing superpower.

Comment: lol. I know..but it will take months and I need to resolve this sooner. Though, I will edit my ps just to avoid more comments on company restrictions :P

Comment: Leave it in, otherwise people will just tell you to use fusion logging.

Comment: @Will So no way to proceed without Fusion here? Anything like best practices? I am guessing conflict is probably because of same enterprise library version but not all dependencies are loaded. But my code does not use validation not sure why it would complain. How can I ensure that my application loads all the required libraries properly?

Comment: I think you will need Fusion Logging to determine exactly what is happening. Sorry. Enterprise Library 5 Common assembly has a soft dependency on Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Validation.dll.  So that is probably where the validation block is entering the picture.  Could the other add in be deploying the validation block assembly?  If so, EntLib would attempt to load the assembly which could cause an issue (perhaps version/signature).  Have you tried deploying the Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Validation.dll Version=5.0.505.0 assembly with your add-in?

Comment: See if you can repro on a machine where you can do fusion logging.  And show the idiots in charge this post so that they can see how they are screwing you and themselves over for such a ridiculous limitation.  There's absolutely no reason to block fusion logging.  They're fools.

Comment: @RandyLevy So, I am using MS signed dlls and deploying them in GAC through my msi. If both the addins use MS signed dlls then will there be any conflicts, even if I do not deploy validation with my msi since I don't use it? Assuming, both the addin are using same version of EntLb ( my deduction based on testing with diff versions of entlib) then this conflict would arise ONLY because they might be changing the signature? and my MS signed  dll is trying to load their signed version of dll and causing conflict?

Comment: And does this mean - it is better that I sign all the dlls that I deploy to avoid conflicts? Will it be safer that way?